# Teradata SQL help. Need help getting the start date and end date (yellow) of the most recent employment status. Thank you

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Teradata SQL help. Need help getting the start date and end date (yellow) of the most recent employment status. Thank you.  Click on the question for [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax7ke.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to get your expected result, based on your data you might apply Teradata's NORMALIZE option, a SQL extension to combine overlapping periods:

```
SELECT NAME, job_title, status, next(Begin(pd)) AS start_date, End(pd) AS end_date
FROM
 ( -- returns one group for consecutive overlapping rows 
   SELECT NORMALIZE
     name, 
     job_title,
     status,
      -- need to subtract 1 to create a valid period
     PERIOD(prior(start_date), end_date) AS pd
   FROM tab
 ) AS dt
QUALIFY
   -- return the latest row only
   Row_Number()
   Over(PARTITION BY name
        ORDER BY start_date DESC) = 1
```

Caution : This returns a new group whenever name, job_title or status change.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dnoeth. Getting an error Invalid date supplied for end_date

Comment: You probably got 9999-12-31 indicating infinity. I will edit my answer to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```sql
SELECT
  t.name, 
  MAX(t.job_title) AS job_title,
  status,
  MIN(t.start_date) AS start_date, 
  MAX(t.end_date) AS end_date
FROM mytable t
GROUP BY t.name, t.status
QUALIFY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY t.name ORDER BY t.start_date DESC) = 1
```

Teradata will do the aggregates first and then apply the window function.  So, this will first get the `MIN/MAX` dates within each person's `status` and then assign a `RANK` to each of these rows based on the most recent `start_date`.

I don't have a system to test, but give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Hi Rav.. your suggestion didn't work with rank function still giving me start date for the same row as max end_date